# Shutting down hosts by script

Tags: marklogic

I want to use [`xdmp:shutdown()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:shutdown)

```
xdmp:shutdown(
   $hostIDs as xs:unsignedLong*,
   $reason as xs:string,
   [$failover as xs:boolean]
) as empty-sequence()
```

What value should I pass in the optional parameter? Does setting it to *true* mean that the master forests in the affected host will failover to its replica forests residing in other hosts? And is it recommended to initiate shutdown from a script? Or we should do it from Admin GUI?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`xdmp:shutdown`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:shutdown) states:

> $failover True if other hosts in the cluster should take over the replica forests. False if not specified.

So yes, you can tell the cluster to failover to replica forests located on other hosts by passing in `fn:true()`.

It depends on what you are trying to achieve whether that is the appropriate thing to do or not. To be honest, I never used `xdmp:shutdown()` myself. In case I needed to take down a node for maintenance, I always used `service MarkLogic stop` from the hosts command-line, which probably does a shutdown with a false as 3rd parameter effectively.

HTH!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more (in your question) about what you are trying to do? E.g. why do you need to shutdown hosts?

Comment: maintenance activity.